# Radare2: pd command ignores cfg.bigendian setting

Tags: radare2, disassemblers

I am currently using `radare2` to disassemble a raw ARM binary (bootloader) in little endian format. I used the command `e cfg.bigendian = false` to set the endianness, but the `pd` command seems to ignore my settings. In particular, I used the following chain of commands:

```
$ r2 -a arm  bootloader.img
[0x00000000]> s 0xa48
[0x00000a48]> e cfg.bigendian = false
[0x00000a48]> pxw 4
0x00000a48  0xe92d41c0  // This is correct
[0x00000a48]> pd 1
0x00000a48      c0412de9  invalid // This is the wrong ordering
```

When I use the following command:

```
[0x00000a48]> e cfg.bigendian = true
[0x00000a48]> pxw 4
0x00000a48  0xc0412de9 
[0x00000a48]> pd 1
0x00000a48      c0412de9       invalid
```

The byte ordering of pxw changes, but the byte ordering of pd does not.

How do I tell `pd` (or any other disassembler command) to assume a certain endianness? I am new to using `radare2`, so it might be that I am missing something here - feel free to point out any mistakes.